# How to make pexpect commands execute without interact() in my program

Tags: python, linux, pexpect

I have this python function using pexpect that looks something like this:

```
  def executeCommandWithOtherUser(command):
    p = pexpect.spawn('su', ['otherUser'])
    p.expect('Password:')
    p.sendline('1234')
    prompt = '.*$'
    p.expect(prompt)
    p.sendline(command)

    #p.interact()
    p.close()
    return
```

When I try this code, it doesn't execute the command (tested using e.g. touch x.txt). I can see the command if I enable pexpect logging but nothing has happened when the program finishes. If I uncomment the line with p.interact() it does work. However, this gives the control to the user and I need to manually exit the program.

**Why doesn't the function execute the command without interact? What can I do to make it work?**

Comment: add `p.expect(prompt)` *after* the command, to wait until the command finishes.

Comment: I tried that, but no change in behaviour.

Comment: escape the dollar sign in the prompt: `r'\$'` (otherwise `$` is a regex meta-character inside the pattern)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But is the problem really with matching the prompt? If it were, the program would timeout on each expect(prompt)? But it does seem to have something to do with not waiting for the remote end (see my comment in the answer from anonymous pyhton hacke). I will try to change the prompt string.

Comment: how about you try it first? My guess (I may be mistaken) is that `'.*$'` pattern matches *anything* (including empty input).

Comment: I tried it and it works :) `prompt = '\$'´ also works (I guess r is a python thing to say it's a regex?) If you write an answer I will accept it, otherwise I will write one myself and credit you.

Comment: `r''` is a raw string *literal* that is often used for Windows paths and regex patterns that contain many backslashes (it allows to put the backslash literally otherwise it often escapes the next character e.g., `'\n'` is a single character (a newline) while `r'\n'` is *two* characters (a backslash + `n`). Post your own answer with the tested code that you know works: [it is explicitly encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). See also, [`pexpect.expect_exact()`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect_exact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the prompt regex is not correctly specified (`prompt = '.*$'`). The current prompt string regex will match also empty inputs because $ has a special regex meaning and is not escaped with \. The below code works:

```
def executeCommandWithOtherUser(command):
  p = pexpect.spawn('su', ['otherUser'])
  p.expect('Password:')
  p.sendline('1234')
  prompt = r'\$'
  p.expect(prompt)
  p.sendline(command)
  p.expect(prompt)
  p.close()
  return
```

An alternative to `expect()` is to use `expect_exact()`, which uses plain string matches instead of regex.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting your command **immediately** after entering a password -- which is BEFORE the remote end is ready to receive your command.

You need to expect a remote prompt before sending your command.

Comment: But isn't that what I do when I write p.expect(prompt) before sendline? I've tried to add expect(prompt) after the sendline(command)) but it doesn't seem to work. Your suggestion led me to try time.sleep after sendline, which actually made it work. So it has something to do with  waiting for prompt.